# Dimensions of kernel and image of composition

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given $A,B\in K^{n\times n}$ with $AB=0$.
I am trying to prove that $rg(A)+rg(B)\leq n$.\

My attempt:
Since $AB=0 \implies \dim(\ker(AB))=n$.

Using dimension formula to calculate dimension of images:
$$\dim(\text{im}(A))+\dim(\ker(A)) = \dim(K^n) = n\\
\dim(\text{im}(B))+\dim(\ker(B)) = \dim(K^n) = n\\
\implies \dim(\text{im}(A))+\dim(\text{im}(B) = 2n-(\dim(\ker(A)+\dim(\ker(B))$$

If I could prove that $$\ker(AB) = \ker(B) \cup (\ker(A)\cap\text{im}(B)) = \ker(A) \cup \ker(B)$$
then I get a lower bound of n for the sum of the dimension of the individual kernels:
$$\dim(\ker(AB)) = n = \dim(\ker(A)) + \dim(\ker(B)) - \dim(\ker(A) \cap \ker(B))\\
\implies n\leq \dim(\ker(A)) + \dim(\ker(B))$$
Which leads to the desired inequality, since $rg(A) = \dim(\text{im}(A))$ (same for $B$).

I am having trouble proving the upper assumption and don't even know if it is true. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We have $AB=0$.

Thus the sequence $\Bbb R^n\stackrel{B}{\rightarrow} \Bbb R^n\stackrel{A}{\rightarrow} 0$

shows that $im(B)\subseteq ker(A)$.

Comment: Doesn't $B$ act before $A$?

Comment: I somehow didn't see that before. That solves my issue. Thank you.